# Two inner joins with same tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I have this problem I've been working on for a while, and I just haven't been able to figure out what's wrong with my query. Today, I finally got a bit closer, and now I think I'm pretty close and not too far from succeeding, but I need your help to spot the mistake in this query, because I think I've stared blind on it. This is the error I get:

"The objects "webpages_UsersInRoles" and "webpages_UsersInRoles" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them."

```
SELECT * FROM Users 
INNER JOIN webpages_UsersInRoles 
ON webpages_UsersInRoles.UserId = Users.UserId 
INNER JOIN webpages_UsersInRoles 
ON webpages_UsersInRoles.RoleId = webpages_Roles.RoleId
WHERE Users.UserId = 1
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you need to `JOIN` to the same table (`webpages_UsersInRoles`), or to `webpages_Roles`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think below is the final query that you need. I have used alias as `TAB1,TAB2 and TAB3` for clarity and to avoid confusion. Change it as required.

```
SELECT * FROM Users TAB1
INNER JOIN webpages_UsersInRoles  TAB2
ON TAB2.UserId = TAB1.UserId 
INNER JOIN webpages_Roles TAB3
ON TAB2.RoleId = TAB3.RoleId
WHERE TAB1.UserId = 1
```

Btw,JUST FOR INFO.... probably you get "`The objects "webpages_UsersInRoles" and "webpages_UsersInRoles" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them.`" error in the line mentioned below from your original query:

```
SELECT * FROM Users 
INNER JOIN webpages_UsersInRoles 
ON webpages_UsersInRoles.UserId = Users.UserId 
INNER JOIN webpages_UsersInRoles 
ON webpages_UsersInRoles.RoleId  -----> Not able to identify which webpages_UsersInRoles  is being called (First inner join or second inner join)
  = webpages_Roles.RoleId
WHERE Users.UserId = 1
```

Comment: @user3250722: Happy to help! If you have enough reputation, please upvote also. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use an alisas for the tables:

```
SELECT * FROM Users 
INNER JOIN webpages_UsersInRoles w1 ON w1.webpages_UsersInRoles.UserId = Users.UserId 
INNER JOIN webpages_UsersInRoles w2 ON w1.webpages_UsersInRoles.RoleId = w2.webpages_Roles.RoleId
WHERE Users.UserId = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I see 3 tables ... `Users`, `webpages_UsersInRoles` and `webpages_Roles`

Only 2 are called.

**`webpages_Roles` ??**

Maybe with `webpages_Roles` in the second join :

```
SELECT * FROM Users 
INNER JOIN webpages_UsersInRoles 
ON webpages_UsersInRoles.UserId = Users.UserId 
INNER JOIN webpages_Roles 
ON webpages_UsersInRoles.RoleId = webpages_Roles.RoleId
WHERE Users.UserId = 1
```

Comment: Gives me this error:
The multi-part identifier "webpages_Roles.RoleId" could not be bound.

Comment: Because there is `webpages_Roles` table which is never called... It's missing in your question. I've edited my answer.